# How to Disable Elastic Bounce in Xamarin iOS 13.2 application?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have a webview that bounces on scroll. Previously i have disabled it by implementing a custom renderer.

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FormsWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control != null)
        {
            Control.ScrollView.Bounces = false;

        }
    }
```

But after updating to 13.2 the above fix is not working.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are also using **UIWebView** to implement that , you can change to use **WKWebView** . Because Apple deprecated `UIWebView` from iOS 13 .

[image: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview]

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {

        public HybridWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration())
        {
        }

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            ScrollView.Bounces = false;
        }

       protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

It works as follow in my local site:

[image]

Comment: i tired your implementation but still i have the bounce effect in other scroll able elements in web application.

Comment: @RashedulAlam Could you share a sample project link here , I will check that . Or you can update the full renderer code in question . I think you can have a check with my renderer code , it maybe different with yours .

Comment: you can find my full implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/RashedulAlam/0323a47526e3728f558a333793f525ef)

Comment: @RashedulAlam From shared code , there is no problem . Do you have a try with other version of iOS ? Because my device and simulator is 13.4 .Later I will share my worked sample project .

Comment: @RashedulAlam Here is my sample project link :https://www.dropbox.com/s/zffm87twobsdtd7/AppWKWebViewSample.rar?dl=0 .It works in iOS 13.4 .

Comment: This is the correct way to prevent bounce effect for webview on iOS application.
However, after further investigation, I found that there were a particular css that was causing the bouncy effect on a particular page and unfortunately it was on the layout page and which makes the whole application to have the same effect.
CSS can also cause this bounce effect on iOS webview application